# What is $ \frac{d \ E(ln(y)|X)}{d \ y}$ in OLS?

Tags: distributions, random-variable, expected-value, derivative, marginal-effect

Assume that the true model (DGP) is

$ ln(y) \ = \ \beta_0 \ + \ \beta_1 ln(x_1) \ + \ \cdots \ + \ \beta_k x_k \ + \ \varepsilon \hspace{3em} \text{where } \ \begin{bmatrix} x_1\\
\vdots\\
x_k\\
\varepsilon \end{bmatrix} \sim IID  \ \text{ and }  \ \varepsilon \sim N(0, \sigma^2) $

The estimated regression model is

$ ln(y) \ = \ \widehat{\beta_0} \ + \ \widehat{\beta_1} ln(x_1) \ + \ \cdots \ + \ \widehat{\beta_k} x_k \ \hspace{3em} \forall \ i \in 1 \ldots n$

So what is the result of $\frac{d\ E(ln(y)|X)}{d\ y}$?

Since $\frac{d\ ln(y)}{d\ y} = \frac{1}{y}$, should it be something like $\frac{1}{ E(ln(y)|X)}$? And how can I prove it?

Thank you for your help!

---

My motivation:

I was told that given the dependent variable is logged, the coefficient of the logged independent variable can be explained as the percentage change: "a one percent change in $ln(x_1)$ is associated with a $\beta_1$ percent change in $ln(y)$." And the math was:

$\begin{equation*}
\beta_1 \hspace{1em} = \hspace{1em} \displaystyle \frac{\partial \ ln(y) }{ \partial \ ln(x_1)} \hspace{1em} = \hspace{1em} \frac{ \displaystyle \frac{\partial \ ln(y) }{\partial \ y} \ \partial \ y }{ \hspace{.7em}  \displaystyle \frac{\partial \ ln(x_1) }{\partial \ x_1 } \ \partial \ x_1 \hspace{.7em}  } \hspace{1em} = \hspace{1em} \frac{\displaystyle \frac{1 }{ y } \ \partial \ y}{  \hspace{.7em}  \displaystyle \frac{1 }{ x_1 } \ \partial \ x_1  \hspace{.7em}  } \hspace{1em} = \hspace{1em} \frac{  \displaystyle  \frac{\partial \ y}{y} }{ \hspace{.7em}  \displaystyle \frac{  \partial \ x_1}{x_1} \hspace{.7em}  } \hspace{1em} = \hspace{1em} \frac{  \displaystyle  \frac{\Delta \ y}{y} }{ \hspace{.7em}  \displaystyle \frac{  \Delta \ x_1}{x_1} \hspace{.7em}  } 
\end{equation*}$

I was trying to make sense of this percent-percent explanation of $\beta_1$. However, I thought that the marginal effect of the independent variable $ln(x_1)$ should be defined by $\displaystyle \frac{\partial \ E(ln(y)|X)}{\partial \ ln(x_1)}$ rather than $\displaystyle \frac{\partial \ ln(y)}{\partial \ ln(x_1)}$ . In this case, the denominator $ \displaystyle \frac{\partial \ ln(x_1) }{\partial \ x_1 } \ \partial \ x_1$ is still the same. But how about the numerator?

By definition, $E(ln(y)|X) \equiv \displaystyle \int \ y f(y|X) \ dy \ $ and I have no idea how to show that the numerator can be expressed into something like $ \displaystyle \frac{\Delta \ y}{y}$...

Comment: As written, that derivative will just be zero because there’s no dependence on $y$ after taking the expected value. Is that what you’re actually looking for?

Comment: Please give more context here. What is it that you are trying to learn or achieve? The question as you have stated it doesn't make any sense for the reasons hinted at by jld. The quantity you say you want to compute is degenerate and I suspect you are really after something different.

Comment: @jld Thanks for the comment! I was actually trying to find $\frac{\partial \ E(ln(y)|X)}{\partial \ ln(x_1)}$ for the log-log marginal effect... and I thought that I might need to compute the asked value (or maybe I was wrong)

Comment: @GordonSmyth Thanks for the comment! I have updated the context. I was trying to find the marginal effect of $ln(x_1)$, and I thought that I might need to compute this term

Comment: No, you're wrong. Differentiating wrt to y is not at all relevant. To be honest, you are making something very straightforward far more difficult than it really is. The percentage effect is on $y$ rather than on $\ln y$ and you don't need any derivatives to show that. Just write down $\exp E(\ln y)$.

Comment: One last comment. There's no assumption in linear regression that $x_1,\ldots,x_k$ are iid. You don't need to make any assumptions about the distribution of x's at all, indeed the whole analysis is conditional on the observed x values.. Only the $\epsilon$ are iid.

Answer (score 2):

The true regression function $u(\mathbf{x}) \equiv \mathbb{E}(\ln y | \mathbf{X} = \mathbf{x})$ is a function of the *regressor vector* $\mathbf{x}$, not the response variable $y$.  (Remember that the expectation operation is an integration --- it "integrates out" the variable of integration.)  Thus, if you take its partial derivative with respect to $y$ you get the trivial result:$^\dagger$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \mathbb{E}(\ln y | \mathbf{x}) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(\mathbf{x}) = 0.$$

---

$^\dagger$ ...assuming you even consider the partial derivative operation to be well-defined with respect to a variable that is not part of the function, which is another matter.